# Tall vertical brace to the right of a column vector

Tags: math-mode, braces

Suppose I have a vector of the form

```
__   __
_  1  _
_  2  _
_  3  _
_  4  _
__   __
```

How can I create a tall brace to the right of this column vector, like this

```
__   __
_  1  _ \
_  2  _  \ Entries
_  3  _  /
_  4  _ /
__   __
```

Comment: You mention a column vector, but you have three columns…

Comment: No no its a column vector for example ```\begin{array}{c}\left[1\\2\\3\\4\\\end{array}\right]```  @Bernard

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting as the term "underbrace" is generally taken to mean a horizontal, downward-pointing curly brace, whereas you're looking for a vertical, right-hand-pointing curly brace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you'd like, the `rcases` environment from  `mathtools` should it (albeit it's not exactly designed for that – it's a version of `cases` with a brace on the right, and it can include conditions):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{rcases}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{rcases}\text{Entries} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other possibilities: using the `blkarray` or the `bigdelim` packages.@Mico

Comment: +1. You may want to mention that the `rcases` environment can do many more things besides inserting a right-facing curly brace.

Comment: @Mico: I  agree it's a distorted use of  rcases. I've added a few words, without going into details, and also mentioned two other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

You could encase the `bmatrix` environment -- which can be used to create matrices as well as column vectors -- in a `\left. ... \right\}` construct.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' env.
\begin{document}
\[
\left. 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} 
\right\} \text{Entries}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you need to (or want to) remove the whitespace padding that's inserted by `\left.` -- as well as, for that matter, by `\begin{rcases}`) -- you could insert the instruction `\mkern-12mu` immediately after `\left.`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just as another alternative....using `aligned` enviroment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\[\left.\begin{aligned}
& \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}  
\end{aligned}\right\}
\text{Entries}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]